# How can I reduce the minimum memory usage of python

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

When I open a python program, I tested that the minimum usage is about 45MB (42Mib). How can I reduce the minimum memory usage? By the way, I tested the minimum usage value by opening python and just printing some strings.

I am using python on my webpage server. It means the code would probably be executed by many people at the same time. The code themselves does not consume that many memories and I have reduced external libs usage as possible as I can. Finally, I found it is not the code, but the program itself consumes the most memory. How can I improve this?

The lib helps me test memory usage is "memory-profiler 0.55.0"

```
@profile
def test_memory():
    print("just a string")
    return
test_memory()
```

Output:

## Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

```
 1   42.801 MiB   42.801 MiB   @profile
 2                             def test_memory():
 3   42.801 MiB    0.000 MiB       print("just a string")
 4   42.801 MiB    0.000 MiB       return
```

Comment: If your web server is ```apache```, you can use ```mod_python``` instead of ```wsgi```. Also its better ```wsgi``` than ```cgi```: http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/introduction.html

Comment: Configure the interpreter to run with optimizations ```-OO``` option. Also check the environment variable ```PYTHONMALLOC``` to customize memory allocators